# Traveling Salesman Problem for visiting cities

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, traveling-salesman, heuristic

> Implement TSP problem using best first algorithm (so it will be
> backtracking, branch-and-bound, and best-first). Since you are looking
> for a cycle, the start/finish city is not important. Therefore we
> assume that start and finish city is always index 0.
>
> For the bound use solution of the relaxed problem as discussed in
> class: TSP uses 2 constraints,
>
> all cities have to be visited, each city is visited once (except the
> start) Try dropping one of them and see if you can solve the resulting
> relaxed problem. Driver calls a function std::vector SolveTSP( char
> const* filename ); return value is a vector of city indices in order
> they are visited. The first and last values are always 0 (start=0,
> ...., finish=0).  Example:
>
> ```
> 0 4 2 1 3 0
> ```
>
> This is an example of a map:
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 2 1 2 
>   1 2 2 
>     2 1 
>       1
> ```
>
> where 5 is the number of cities.

I've coded a nearest neighbour heuristic and it solved half of the test cases. The rest of the cases timed out because the algorithm took too long. I asked around and a friend suggested having an early exit so that the algo won't have to continue calculating when the current path costs more than the best path. It solved 70% of the test cases but the last 3 test cases are still being timed out (the last 3 test cases are the hardest). Are there any more ways I can optimize my code?

This is my tsp.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

const int INF = INT_MAX;

struct State {
    int city;
    int level;
    vector<int> path;
    int visited; // Bitmask to represent visited cities
    int cost;

    State(int _city, int _level, const vector<int>& _path, int _visited, int _cost)
        : city(_city), level(_level), path(_path), visited(_visited), cost(_cost) {}

    bool operator>(const State& other) const {
        return cost > other.cost;
    }
};

int CalculateLowerBound(const State& current, const vector<int>& distances, int numCities) {
    int lowerBound = current.cost;

    for (int city = 0; city < numCities; ++city) {
        if (!(current.visited & (1 << city))) {
            int minDist = INF;

            // Find the two smallest distances to unvisited cities
            for (int nextCity = 0; nextCity < numCities; ++nextCity) {
                if (city != nextCity && !(current.visited & (1 << nextCity))) {
                    minDist = min(minDist, distances[city * numCities + nextCity]);
                }
            }

            lowerBound += minDist;
        }
    }

    return lowerBound;
}

vector<int> readInput(char const* filename, int& numCities) {
    ifstream input(filename);
    input >> numCities;

    vector<int> distances(numCities * numCities);

    // Read distance values and store them in the flattened vector
    for (int i = 0; i < numCities; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numCities; ++j) {
            int distance;
            input >> distance;
            distances[i * numCities + j] = distances[j * numCities + i] = distance;
        }
    }

    return distances;
}

int CalculateDistance(int city1, int city2, const vector<pair<int, int>>& cityCoordinates) {
    int x1 = cityCoordinates[city1].first;
    int y1 = cityCoordinates[city1].second;
    int x2 = cityCoordinates[city2].first;
    int y2 = cityCoordinates[city2].second;

    // Calculate Euclidean distance
    double dx = x1 - x2;
    double dy = y1 - y2;
    double distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    // Return the distance as an integer (rounding to the nearest integer)
    return static_cast<int>(distance + 0.5);
}

vector<int> SolveTSP(char const* filename) {
    int numCities;
    vector<int> distances = readInput(filename, numCities);

    // Initialize the initial state
    vector<int> initialPath = { 0 }; // Start at city 0
    int visited = 1; // Start city is visited
    State initial(0, 0, initialPath, visited, 0);

    // Priority queue for best-first search
    priority_queue<State, vector<State>, greater<State>> pq;
    pq.push(initial);

    // Initialize the best tour and its cost
    vector<int> bestTour;
    int bestCost = INF;

    while (!pq.empty()) {
        State current = pq.top();
        pq.pop();

        // Calculate the lower bound
        int lowerBound = CalculateLowerBound(current, distances, numCities);

        if (lowerBound >= bestCost) {
            continue; // Skip this path as it cannot lead to a better solution
        }

        if (current.level == numCities - 1) {
            // If all cities have been visited, add the return to start city and update best tour if necessary
            current.path.push_back(0);
            current.cost += distances[current.city * numCities];

            if (current.cost < bestCost) {
                bestTour = current.path;
                bestCost = current.cost;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int nextCity = 0; nextCity < numCities; ++nextCity) {
                if (!(current.visited & (1 << nextCity))) {
                    // Create a new state for each unvisited city
                    vector<int> newPath = current.path;
                    newPath.push_back(nextCity);

                    int newVisited = current.visited | (1 << nextCity);

                    int newCost = current.cost + distances[current.city * numCities + nextCity];

                    pq.push(State(nextCity, current.level + 1, newPath, newVisited, newCost));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestTour;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## limited set size

```
struct State {
    ...
    int visited; // Bitmask to represent visited cities
```

The C++ containers library offers perfectly good datastructures.
It's odd that you chose not to use <del>an unordered_set</del> `std::vector<bool>`, as G. Sliepen observes.

You didn't make any effort to obtain a wide integer
when running on "small" word servers, such as a 32-bit host.

Choosing to interpret the initial bit as a sign bit
can make debugging this code needlessly inconvenient.

Some TSP instances are easy to solve despite
having a high city count.
For example, a hundred cities stretched out along
[I-95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_95)
would lead to a fairly obvious solution.

(Using `int` rather than `double` for `cost`
was perhaps a somewhat odd design choice,
but I suppose it will work fine, without too many ties.)

```
        }
        else {
```

Please use a code pretty-printer / auto-formatter, to improve legibility.

Thank you for breaking out the `CalculateLowerBound` helper,
it looks very nice and logical.
I *do* worry that its quadratic cost may be trouble.
Hopefully we don't ask it same question repeatedly,
as the returned result is not memoized.

---

## algorithm

> any more ways i can optimize ?

The "iterate over each unvisited city" loop is simple and straightforward.
Changing the order in which we consider each candidate
might allow the `current.cost < bestCost` test to prune more effectively.
Essentially we want to get a "pretty good" `bestCost` early on.
You might try either of these two approaches:

1. Visit a random permutation of cities, rather than in the given sequential order.
2. Order candidates by distance from `current`.
3. Almost the same thing, use a quad-tree representation and visit candidates with same quad-tree prefix as `current` before visiting more distant candidates.

Comment: I have seen code styles that consistently put `else` with the opening brace, but not with the preceding brace, just like this.  I don't like them, but they do exist.

Comment: While using an `int` bitmask is a bad choice, `std::vector<bool>` would be fine, and better than using a `std::unordered_set` when it comes to both speed and memory usage.